# How to make multi-select, aucomplete combo box like in Atlassian Jira

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I like GUI and controls of Atlassian Jira. In particular they have cool multi-select combo control. I need to implement similar control on my site.

I am using jquery-ui.

What library do they use? What license?

Can I find it somewhere as JScript?

Is there anything similar free or commercial?

Developer website with demo:
http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/tour/

UPDATE SAMPLE IMAGE

[image]

Comment: Why don't you provide a link to a page with the functionality you describe?

Comment: can you put the link of website ?

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/ — I've seen this project recently on [DaylyJS](http://dailyjs.com/).

Comment: Here is a simple one that is based off the [jQuery UI combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox). https://github.com/dschu012/jquery-multicombobox

Comment: Its similar to a combobox but displays checkboxes in items for multiple selection. Also it is written in pure javascript and can be extended. http://asimishaq.com/resources/tools/multi-select-dropdown-list/

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#placeholders)